# Duplicate rows/columns for the same primary key in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table/columnfamily in Cassandra 3.7 with sensordata.

```
CREATE TABLE test.sensor_data (
    house_id int,
    sensor_id int,
    time_bucket int,
    sensor_time timestamp,
    sensor_reading map<int, float>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((house_id, sensor_id, time_bucket), sensor_time)
)
```

Now when I select from this table I find duplicates for the same primary key, something I thought was impossible.

```
cqlsh:test> select * from sensor_data;

 house_id | sensor_id | time_bucket | sensor_time                     | sensor_reading
----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------+----------------
        1 |         2 |           3 | 2016-01-02 03:04:05.000000+0000 |       {1: 101}
        1 |         2 |           3 | 2016-01-02 03:04:05.000000+0000 |       {1: 101}
```

I think part of the problem is that this data has both been written "live" using java and Datastax java driver, and it has been loaded together with historic data from another source using sstableloader.

Regardless, this shouldn't be possible. 
I have no way of connecting with the legacy cassandra-cli to this cluster, perhaps that would have told me something that I can't see using cqlsh.

So, the questions are:
* Is there anyway this could happen under known circumstances?
* Can I read more raw data using cqlsh? Specifically write time of these two rows. the writetime()-function can't operate on primary keys or collections, and that is all I have.

Thanks.

Update:

This is what I've tried, from comments, answers and other sources
* selecting using blobAsBigInt gives the same big integer for all identical rows
* connecting using cassandra-cli, after enabling thrift, is possible but reading the table isn't. It's not supported after 3.x
* dumping out using sstabledump is ongoing but expected to take another week or two ;)

Comment: can you check the data with cassandra-cli ?

Comment: No, cassandra-cli is not supported in 3.x. I could do sstabledump but the datafiles are huge and that tool offers no filtering.

Comment: I believe sensor_time is different for both rows, but are truncated and shown as if the time is same. You can also ask at Cassandra mailing list too.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what happened ?

Comment: No. I changed to code to remove duplicates, if ever found. I guess the "bug", or whatever this is, is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect to see nanoseconds in a timestamp field and additionally i'm of the impression they're fully not supported?  Try this:

`SELECT house_id, sensor_id, time_bucket, blobAsBigint(sensor_time) FROM test.sensor_data;`

I WAS able to replicate it doing by inserting the rows via an integer:

`INSERT INTO sensor_data(house_id, sensor_id, time_bucket, sensor_time) VALUES (1,2,4,1451692800000);
INSERT INTO sensor_data(house_id, sensor_id, time_bucket, sensor_time) VALUES (1,2,4,1451692800001);`

This makes sense because I would suspect one of your drivers is using a bigint to insert the timestamp, and one is likely actually using the datetime.

Tried playing with both timezones and bigints to reproduce this... seems like only bigint is reproducable

```
 house_id | sensor_id | time_bucket | sensor_time              | sensor_reading
----------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------
        1 |         2 |           3 | 2016-01-02 00:00:00+0000 |           null
        1 |         2 |           4 | 2016-01-01 23:00:00+0000 |           null
        1 |         2 |           4 | 2016-01-02 00:00:00+0000 |           null
        1 |         2 |           4 | 2016-01-02 00:00:00+0000 |           null
        1 |         2 |           4 | 2016-01-02 01:01:00+0000 |           null
```

edit: Tried some shenanigans using bigint in place of datetime insert, managed to reproduce...

Comment: Inserting with integers like you do gives me two rows as well, however, they show different values printed both normally and with `blobAsBigInt`. When running this against my large cluster I get the same values for `blobAsBigInt` for all 3 rows.

Comment: @Andreas well, i'm kinda at a loss then.  with what i know about cassandra what you have there shouldn't be possible.  I'b be interested to know what your investigation shows.

As a second thought, are you querying more than one node?  What is the output from describe test.sensor_data?

Comment: I can see from `tracing on` that I only query one node. Querering the other nodes or adding `consistency all` yields the same result so this "error" is on all the nodes holding the data.

Comment: Well,  seems like a bug...  I'd verify with describe table and make sure keys were in fact the same...  And try and replicate the issue....

Answer (score 1):

Adding some observations on top of what [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964080/nick) mentioned,

> Cassandra Primary key = one or combination of {Partition key(s) + Clustering key(s)}

Keeping in mind the concepts of partition keys used within angular brackets which can be simple (one key) or composite (multiple keys) for unique identification and clustering keys to sort data, the below have been observed.

- **Query using select:** sufficient to query using all the partition key(s) provided, additionally can query using clustering key(s) but in the same order in which they have been mentioned in primary key during table creation.
- **Update using set or update:** the update statement needs to have search/condition clauses which not only include all the partition key(s) but also all the clustering key(s)

***Answering the question - Is there anyway this could happen under known circumstances?***

*Yes, it is possible when same data is inserted from different sources.*

To explain further, incase one tries to insert data from code (API etc) into Cassandra and then tries inserting the same data from DataStax Studio/any tool used to perform direct querying, a duplicate record is inserted.
Incase the same data is being pushed multiple times either from code alone or querying tool alone or from another source used to do the same operation multiple times, the data behaves idempotently and is not inserted again.

The possible explanation could be the way the underlying storage engine computes internal indexes or hashes to identify a row pertaining to set of columns (since column based).

**Note:**

The above information of duplicacy incase same data is pushed from different sources has been observed, tested and validated.

Language used: C#

Framework: .NET Core 3

Answer (score 0):

"sensor_time" is part of the primary key. It is not in "Partition Key", but is "Clustering Column". this is why you get two "rows".

However, in the disk table, both "visual rows" are stored on single Cassandra row. In reality, they are just different columns and CQL just pretend they are two "visual rows".

**Clarification** - I did not worked with Cassandra for a while so I might not use correct terms. When i say "visual rows", I mean what CQL result shows.

**Update**

You can create following experiment (please ignore and fix any syntax errors I will do).

This suppose to do table with composite primary key:

- "state" is "Partition Key" and
- "city" is "Clustering Column".

  create table cities(
     state int,
     city int,
     name text,
     primary key((state), city)
  );

  insert into cities(state, city, name)values(1, 1, 'New York');
  insert into cities(state, city, name)values(1, 2, 'Corona');

  select * from cities where state = 1;

this will return something like:

```
1, 1, New York
1, 2, Corona
```

But on the disk this will be stored on single row like this:

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
| state | city = 1        | city = 2        |
|       +-----------------+-----------------+
|       | city | name     | city | name     |
+-------+------+----------+------+----------+
| 1     | 1    | New York | 2    | Corona   |
+-------+------+----------+------+----------+
```

When you have such composite primary key you can select or delete on it, e.g.

```
select * from cities where state = 1;
delete from cities where state = 1;
```

In the question, primary key is defined as:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((house_id, sensor_id, time_bucket), sensor_time)
```

this means

- "house_id", "sensor_id", "time_bucket" is "Partition Key" and
- "sensor_time" is the "Clustering Column".

So when you select, the real row is spitted and show as if there are several rows.

**Update**

http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/primary-keys-in-cql/

> The PRIMARY KEY definition is made up of two parts: the Partition Key
>   and the Clustering Columns. The first part maps to the storage engine
>   row key, while the second is used to group columns in a row. In the
>   storage engine the columns are grouped by prefixing their name with
>   the value of the clustering columns. This is a standard design pattern
>   when using the Thrift API. But now CQL takes care of transposing the
>   clustering column values to and from the non key fields in the table.

Then read the explanations in "The Composite Enchilada".

Comment: I don't think this is true, at least not after 3.x. Regardless of how it's saved, it should be filtered when read if the entire primary key is the same.

Comment: there was great explanation for this somewhere in datastax website, but I can not find it. I will edit with experiment you can do.